# Knots and anti-knots in 3+ dimensions

Tags: general-topology, mathematical-physics

I know that it is not possible to tie two knots in a one- dimensional string, such that the knots can untie each other.  Are there objects analogous to knots in spaces with higher numbers of dimensions, which are stable alone but which *can* "untie" each other, or combine into a single simpler  and topologically distinct object?

Edited 6/3/18: Please forgive any incorrect terminology; topology isn't my field of study. I'm asking this from a physics perspective.  The idea that particles might be "knots" in the geometry of space isn't new, but I haven't found articles that address the idea of "knots and anti-knots", which might be a good model for   particle - antiparticle creation and annihilation.

Antiparticles are very much like particles that have been reflected in the time axis, so pairs of objects that could make the analogy work would in some sense be reflections of each other.  It might be that the kind of object needed might exist only in certain spaces with a complex metric, if it exists at all.

One helpful person (@ArnaudMortier) pointed out that braids can cancel each other out.  That's easy to visualize and may turn out to be useful.  However, the braids that come to mind require an already multiply connected substrate: a bundle of at least three long strands.  I'm hoping that there might exist 3- or 4-dimensional sub-manifolds that can be created in pairs via a continuous deformation of a complex 4-manifold.  Reversability of that process would allow for annihilation as well as creation of the pairs. End edit 6/3/18

Comment: Very close to knots: braids. They form a group if you fix the number of strands, which means amongst other things that they can be untied by concatenation with other braids (analogous to the connected sum of knots). But I am pretty sure that this example has already been thought of in the way you intend.

Comment: The ideal kind of object would be relatively simple, and would come in "quasi-opposites" which don't  add up to zero, but instead add up to something topologically distinct.  An electron and positron don't simply annihilate; they convert into one or more photons.

Comment: Smooth structures on higher dimensionals sphere can cancel each other out when you do connect-sum. Vector bundles under Whitney sum are another example, where two twisted bundles can add to give a trivial bundle.

Comment: Would you be willing to put that into a more complete answer, with some references?

Comment: @S.McGrew, sorry I just saw your comment now. You need to ping people with "@" in order for them to get notified. You can refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_sphere for smooth structures on spheres, with the key observation being that they form a finite group! The theory of vector bundles is rather involved. I learned about it in Milnor and Stasheff's book "Characteristic classes."